# Return an array from get_terms and store as JavaScript array for search autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, advanced-taxonomy-queries, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use wp_list_pluck to return an array of taxonomy names from get_terms. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but this only echo's out "Array":

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'state',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' );

    echo $term_ids;
```

Do you know how I can echo out an array of taxonomy names?

The reason I am doing this is because I am wanting to get an array to convert it to a Javascript array of names using json_encode.

Basically I'm using jQuery Autocomplete and would like to get my taxonomy names listed as suggestions to search for:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode( $term_ids ) ?>
```

Perhaps there is possibly a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it simply using:

```
$json = array();

    $terms = get_terms( 'state' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $json[]=array( 'value'=> $term->name );
    }

    echo json_encode($json)
```

Comment: For an autocomplete script it's better to have `label` and `value` .

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake in your code `wp_list_pluck()` returns an array, not a single value. So when you echo `$term_ids`, you are trying to output an array directly, which PHP will only display as `Array`. Instead, you should use `json_encode()` to convert the array into a JSON string.

replace this line

```
echo $term_ids;
```

to

```
echo json_encode($term_ids);
```